# Eclipse linker error: cannot include httpClient - cocos2d-x 3.2

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, cocos2d-x

I am trying to make network call from cocos2d-x 3.2 and I am getting error while compiling that

> HttpClient not found

Although I have included the file

> include "network/HttpClient.h"

and I am getting error at

> cocos2d::network::HttpClient::getInstance()->send(request);

I was getting the same error in visual studio and I resolved that by adding libnetwork sln project but how to do it in **eclipse**.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I added these two lines into Android.mk and after that the issue is cleared.

```
LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES += cocos_network_static

$(call import-module,network)
```

Hoping it helps for you.